# Items in context menu in Lubuntu

Tags: openbox, lxde, mime-types

I am using Lubuntu 11.10. When I call the context menu (right click) many programs appear to open some file.

For example, for `.tex` files, besides TeXstudio and Leafpad, Gnumeric (what a strange option!) and text editor also appear.

So, I'd like to remove those bad options. For some extensions (`.txt` for example) I could remove the wrong programs by deleting the `.desktop` files somewhere in `.config` subfolders.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, copy files like `/usr/share/applications/XX.desktop`, to `~/.local/share/applications`,

And remove the unnecessary mimetypes, from the `Mimetype=` line

(You might need to re-login, not sure if LXDE reloades them automatically)